# Changing Default RDP port on Azure

Tags: azure

Using the resource model I am unable to change the default RDP port.

Is there a trick?

I have updated "Inbound security rules" to a different port but nothing happens and I can't see options elsewhere.

It used to be as simple as changing the endpoints which is no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

If you want another TCP port for RDP Connection, you have to configure the new port number on your Windows VM and create a new endpoint access rule

To do this operation :

1- Start Registry Editor.
2- Locate and then click the following registry subkey:
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TerminalServer\WinStations\RDP-Tcp\PortNumber
3- On the Edit menu, click Modify, and then click Decimal.
4- Type the new port number, and then click OK.
5- Quit Registry Editor.
6- Restart the computer.

On Azure Management console or using Powershell or Azure CLI, create an Endpoint to allow inbound TCP trafic on the port you configure

Regards

Stanislas

Comment: the new resource model "doesn't have endpoints" only classic VM'S have endpoints

Comment: OK Endpoint for VM in ASM.   Network Security Group in ARM (it's one of the five resource of a standard 1 nic VM), just edit Inbound Security Rules of the NSG associated with your VM.

Comment: You forgot to mention that you need to update Windows Firewall to allow access via the changed port number. I just followed your instructions and bricked a VM that I'd spent two days setting up.

Comment: Just to follow up on my previous comment (which was not an April fools joke), I stupidly managed to brick another VM by configuring an FTP server to use the same port number that I was using for RDP and thus lost the ability to get into contact with the VM. It cost me a "technical support incident", but a very nice Microsoft Azure support guy was able to reset the RDP port number using a PowerShell virtual machine extension.

Answer (score 1):

You are currently working with Network Security Groups, which are somehow equivalent to firewall rules, but don't provide port forwarding (which seems to be what you need).

[Azure documentation on endpoints (Classic)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-set-up-endpoints/) mentions this and points to an article to setup load balancing in front of your VM, which can provide "Inbound NAT rules" in a similar way to what endpoints provided in Classic:

> Please note network security groups control access to the virtual
> machine, but they don't provide port forwarding capabilities. To do
> port forwarding, see the following article:
>
> - [Get started configuring an internet facing load balancer using Azure Resource Manager](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/load-balancer-arm-powershell/)

**This is how I understand the situation:**

In Classic you always had an instance of the Azure Load Balancer in front of your VM, so you were provided with a VIP address. This was called a *Cloud Service*. It was on that VIP address where you did the port forwarding (different port on the VIP than on the private IP - known as DIP) as the VIP address was actually assigned to the load balancer, hence servicing all the potential VMs in the same Cloud Service, you had to explicitly *permit* traffic from Internet to a specific VM (unless you wanted a load-balanced endpoint).

Now with Azure Resource Manager and the new portal, by default you don't get a load balancer in front of your VM, so instead of getting a VIP address you get an Instance-Level IP address (ILPIP) attached to the VM and a [Network Security Group (NSG)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/network-security-groups/) that only permits inbound RDP, but permits any outbound traffic. Why do you need an NSG now? Because an ILPIP is assigned only to that VM, so there's no need to explicitly create endpoints as all your ports would be available (it's a one-to-one NAT, similar to the concept of *static NAT* on Cisco ASA). For security reasons you get this NSG applied by default, too. Of course you could choose to not have it, to use a different one or just modify this one (which is what you've been doing).

You can't do port forwarding with NSG because they're only security rules, not NAT rules. You need to be able to work with NAT rules in order to do port forwarding, hence you need Azure Load Balancer in front of your VM and to leverage *Inbound NAT Rules*.